# Weird IP in Linux Mint 17

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, linux-mint, broadcom

I installed Linux Mint over a shared Ethernet connection from my laptop and installed my Broadcom Drivers over that shared ethernet connection, and I noticed that my Linux box is on the wrong gateway. It's pointing to a Verizon IP for the default gateway instead of 192.168.1.1, and it also shares the same public IP as my laptop.

Any ideas? I dun gooft.

Also, the wireless device is under `wlan0` if that's significant to anyone.

ifconfig:

```
wlan0 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr macaddress  
      inet addr:96.253.199.123  Bcast:96.253.199.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::222:5fff:fefe:28af/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:17965 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:10735
      TX packets:10978 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:23494535 (23.4 MB)  TX bytes:846949 (846.9 KB)
      Interrupt:17 Base address:0xc000
```

Comment: This looks like it probably has more to do with your router setup than anything on the linux box itself, as the normal behavior for at least a home router with a single IP coming in via the WAN interface is to NAT and provide local IP's (most are in 192.168.x.x, but theoretically 10.x.x.x and 172.16.x.x-172.31.255.255 are also fair game). The more information you can provide about your network setup, the better.  Neither of your computers should likely be assigned a public IP unless you've gone out of your way to have this be the case.

Comment: Well it looks like my laptop's public IP became the internal IP for the Linux box. It's not my router because this didn't happen on any of my other machines.